# Powershell to get active user OU, username, and group memberships

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a powershell script to export all users in an OU and sub OUs which I can do fine, but when I try to get the user's OU, I get nothing for the OU. I have looked all over online and found a few scripts that pull just the user's OU, but they are a little slow and I can't seem to get them to pull groups or is for pulling from one group instead of listing all users and their groups.
I am trying to export this list and sort by OU so that I can ensure each student is in the proper groups. We have had a few students that were in extra groups and I want a quick and easy look to find those students.

```
#Student
$Report = @()
#Collect all users
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Student,DC=domain,DC=com' -Properties distinguishedname, Name, GivenName, SurName, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, MemberOf, Enabled -ResultSetSize $Null
# Use ForEach loop, as we need group membership for every account that is collected.
# MemberOf property of User object has the list of groups and is available in DN format.
Foreach($User in $users){
$UserGroupCollection = $User.MemberOf
#This Array will hold Group Names to which the user belongs.
$UserGroupMembership = @()
#To get the Group Names from DN format we will again use Foreach loop to query every DN and retrieve the Name property of Group.
Foreach($UserGroup in $UserGroupCollection){
$GroupDetails = Get-ADGroup -Identity $UserGroup
#Here we will add each group Name to UserGroupMembership array
$UserGroupMembership += $GroupDetails.Name
}
#As the UserGroupMembership is array we need to join element with ',' as the seperator
$Groups = $UserGroupMembership -join ','
#Creating custom objects
$Out = New-Object PSObject
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name DistinguishedName -Value @{Name="DistinguishedName";Expression={$_.distinguishedname | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^.+?(?<!\\),',''}}}
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Name -Value $User.Name
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name UserName -Value $User.SamAccountName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Status -Value $User.Enabled
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Groups -Value $Groups
$Report += $Out
}
#Output to screen as well as csv file.
$Report | Sort-Object DistinguishedName | FT -AutoSize
$Report | Sort-Object DistinguishedName | Export-Csv -Path $env:temp\students.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, I added some comments to help you understand the thought process.
This should be a lot faster than what you were doing.

The problem while adding your OUs was here:

```
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name DistinguishedName -Value @{Name="DistinguishedName";Expression={$_.distinguishedname | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^.+?(?<!\\),',''}}}
```

Which should've been:

```
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name DistinguishedName -Value ($user.distinguishedname -replace '^.+?(?<!\\),','')
```

```
#Student
$Report = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()
# Using Collection.Generic.List instead of System.Array for efficiency

#Collect all users

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Student,DC=domain,DC=com' -Properties MemberOf
# -> Use -SearchScope Subtree if you want to go all the way down in OU recursion starting from the 'OU=Student'
# -> distinguishedname, Name, GivenName, SurName, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName and Enabled are Default Properties 
#    of Get-ADUser, no need to call them.
# -> -ResultSetSize $Null is default for Get-ADUSer, no need to call it

# Use ForEach loop, as we need group membership for every account that is collected.
# MemberOf property of User object has the list of groups and is available in DN format.
Foreach($User in $users)
{
    #This Array will hold Group Names to which the user belongs.
    $UserGroupMembership = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]::new()
    #To get the Group Names from DN format we will again use Foreach loop to query every DN and retrieve the Name property of Group.
    Foreach($UserGroup in $User.MemberOf)
    {
        # $GroupDetails = Get-ADGroup -Identity $UserGroup
        # -> Instead of this, we can do some string manipulation
        #    which will be a lot faster and give you the same results.
        $UserGroupMembership.Add($UserGroup.Split(',OU=')[0].replace('CN=',''))
    }
    #As the UserGroupMembership is array we need to join element with ',' as the seperator
    $Groups = $UserGroupMembership -join ','
    #Creating custom objects

    <#
    $Out = New-Object PSObject
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name DistinguishedName -Value @{Name="DistinguishedName";Expression={$_.distinguishedname | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^.+?(?<!\\),',''}}}
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Name -Value $User.Name
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name UserName -Value $User.SamAccountName
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Status -Value $User.Enabled
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Groups -Value $Groups
    $Report += $Out

    -> Again, Add-Member is highly inefficient compared to casting PSCustomObject
    -> += is evil ( •̀ᴗ•́ )و ̑̑
    #>

    $Report.Add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            OrganizationalUnit = ($user.DistinguishedName -replace '^.+?(?<!\\),','')
            Name = $user.Name
            UserName = $user.sAMAccountName
            Status = $user.Enabled
            Membership = $Groups
    })
}

#Output to screen as well as csv file.
$Report | Sort-Object OrganizationalUnit | FT -AutoSize
$Report | Sort-Object OrganizationalUnit | Export-Csv -Path $env:temp\students.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many users you have but every time you += on an array the entire array plus the new element is copied to a completely new array.  This is a bad practice and gets exponentially worse with every item added the array.   You can avoid this by building the arrays as a loop result or by using dotnet *list* object with an efficient add() method.

You also look up the same group names repeatedly.  I don't know the numbers but it's probably a lot better to put all your groups in a hashtable once and then look them up.

Your question is unclear, but if you want a list of users and their groups, you are going the long way around. You mention the ou but AFAICS there is no org unit used in the code.  Do you want the AD ou property or a part of the DN?  You don't seem to be using either.
Note that the DN is a string and sorting by DN will just give an alpha string sort which is not helpful.  Are your students in separate org units under OU=students ?  This is not clear.  If so, use the AD canonicalName to sort the list.

No need to include default properties in -property.  Splatting is nice.

You should improve your question by indicating what your AD structure looks like and what you think your output should look like.

Also, format your code for readability.

You want something along these lines:

```
# group hashtable, for efficient name lookup
$groupName = @{}
$ignoredGroups = @( 'AllStudents','AllUsers', 'etc' ) # don't clutter list with these groups 
Get-AdGroup -filter '*' |                         # any restrictions? searchbase, etc 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ( $ignoredGroups -notcontains $_.Name ) {
      $groupName[ $_.distinguishedName ] = $_.Name
    }  
  }

# ADsplat, for readability 
$AD_Splat = @{
  Filter        = '*'
  SearchBase    = 'OU=Student,DC=domain,DC=com'  
  Properties    = 'MemberOf,CanonicalName,sn,givenName'.split(',')   # split to array 
  ResultSetSize = $Null                    # !? also, there are system limits to size
}
 
$results = Get-ADUser @ad_splat |
   ForEach-Object {
     $DN     = $_.distinguishedName  # do you need this at all?
     $CName  = $_.canonicalName  # for sorting by AD org unit
     $XName  = $_.sn + ', ' + $_.givenName  
     if ( $_.Enabled ) { $Enabled = 'Y'} else { $Enabled = '.' }
     $groups = (
        $_.memberOf | 
        ForEach-Object { $GroupName[ $_ ] } | # lookup name 
        where-Object { $_ } |                 # ignore nulls (when group not in hashtable)
        sort-object                           # consistent ordering between users
      ) -join ';'                             # don't use comma, csv conflict

      # leave custom object in pipe! This builds the array efficiently.
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    DistinguishedName = $dn
    Name              = $_.name
    XName             = $XName
    Login             = $_.SamAccountName
    CName             = $CName
    Groups            = $Groups
    }
} | Sort-Object CName   # sort the objects by canonical name

$results | format-table
$results | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\usersgroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this guys! As I suspected, our student groups are FUBAR and I am going to need to rewrite my scripts for when students advance to the next grade.
@Santiago-Squarzon, when retrieving groups the Split(',CN=') only returned CN,CN,CN. I changed it to (',') and it pulled the groups perfectly.
jim-birch, thanks for your input also.

Comment: @GabrielClifton I'm using `$UserGroup.Split(',OU=')[0].replace('CN=','')` in my code, which should work fine for any `DistinguishedName`